# How to highlight a specific region of a line changing linetype or size using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I have the following dataframe:

```
test = structure(list(Student = c("Ana", "Brenda", "Max", "Ana", "Brenda", 
"Max", "Ana", "Brenda", "Max"), Month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("January", "February", "March"
), class = "factor"), Grade = c(7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 
10L), Change = c("February", "February", "February", "February", 
"February", "February", "February", "February", "February")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

I plotted the grades of each student throughout the months, and wanted to know if there is a simple way to accentuate a specific part of each plotted line that would correspond to the period of time which showed the greatest shift in their grades (this info is already present in the dataset: column "Change". In this case, for all students it would be from February to March).

Trying to use a similar logic as presented [here, to change the color a specific part of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365052/geom-line-different-colour-in-the-same-line) I attempted to change the linetype and/or size of the line (since I already used the color to group and display each student) in order to highlight that particular portion of the line. However, it doesn't seem to be as straightforward.

My attempts were the following:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = Month, y = Grade, color = Student, group = Student)) + 
+     geom_point() + geom_line(data = test, aes(linetype = (ifelse(Month == Change, "solid", "dashed"))))
```

Which yielded the error:

```
Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line
```

And

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = Month, y = Grade, color = Student, group = Student)) + 
    geom_point() + geom_line(data = test, aes(size = (ifelse(Month == Change, 1, 0.8))))
```

Which kinda does what I'm looking for, but looks horrible, and doesn't really seem like its using the size of the line that I'm trying to specify:

[image: This is how it looks]

How do I fix it? Thanks in advance! n_n

Comment: @tjebo you are entirely right. Editing it right now! Though it is a typo that is present only in the post. Just verified that my test dataset in R has this typo fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't specify the size in aes. Use the scale function

For another suggestion regarding line design see below.

```r
test = structure(list(Student = c("Ana", "Brenda", "Max", "Ana", "Brenda", 
                                  "Max", "Ana", "Brenda", "Max"), Month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("January", "February", "March"
                                                                                      ), class = "factor"), Grade = c(7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                      10L), Change = c("Februrary", "Februrary", "Februrary", "Februrary", 
                                                                                                                                       "Februrary", "Februrary", "Februrary", "Februrary", "Februrary"
                                                                                                                      )), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
## typo corrected
test$Change <- "February"

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(test, aes(x = Month, y = Grade, color = Student, group = Student)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ## don't specify size in aes
  geom_line(data = test, aes(size = Month == Change)) +
  ## change the size scale
  scale_size_manual(values = c(`TRUE` = 2, `FALSE` = .8))
```

[image]

Another option might be to make use of the `ggforce::geom_link` functions, which interpolate aesthetics between two points.

```r
library(ggforce)

ggplot(test, aes(x = Month, y = Grade, color = Student, group = Student)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_link2(data = test, aes(size = Grade, ), lineend = "round")
```

[image]

This fails when trying to change the line type. In this case, use geom_segment instead - you will need some data transformation though.

```r
library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  group_by(Student) %>%
  mutate(xend = lead(Month), yend = lead(Grade)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Grade, color = Student, group = Student)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend, linetype = Month == Change)) +
  # need to specify your x
  scale_x_discrete(limits = unique(test$Month))
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess it was quite straightforward... And I agree, your suggestion seems like the better option for sure. I'm guessing then that is not possible then to switch the linetype throughout the line at all, right?

Comment: @JohnSandman Interestingly, changing the line type seems to fail indeed. An option would be to use geom_segment instead, but that requires some data transformation. I believe Allan's visualisation would be much more convincing though

Comment: How would one go about changing the linetype of a segment more than once (eg if there was a drop from 10 to 5, then back to 10 the next month)? I tried using a list in the column "Change" and using "%in%" instead of "==", but I didn't do the trick and I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: @JohnSandman might be worth a follow up question - it's always better to have those questions more visible for future readers. please don't forget to link to this question and of course to add a reproducible example with such an example change. Also, I might  not be able to answer the question, as a lot of work currently, but there will be plenty of people willing to help:)

Answer (score 2):

Changing the line width along its course is possible (as tjebo points out), but it rarely makes for a nice plot. A clearer way might be simply to add a coloured background over the area of interest:

```r
library(hrbrthemes)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(test, aes(x = Month, y = Grade, color = Student, group = Student)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0) +
  geom_rect(data = test[1,],
            aes(xmin = 'February', xmax = 'March', ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
            color = NA, fill = 'deepskyblue4', alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = 'white', size = 3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('pink3', 'orange2', 'red4')) +
  theme_tinyhand()
```

[image]

Comment: this is of course the nicer option

Comment: Thanks Allan! This looks neat and overall a better approach to highlighting the areas I'm interested in. I do have to say however that in this dummy set it looks particularly good because all major "grade shifts" happened in the same month, which is not the case in my dataset, so it seems like I'll have to give it some tweaks to make it work so that it highlights the appropriate region for each observation and I'm still a total noob in R :( But I'll certainly give it a try! as it looks so much nicer.